# Scala: Bad inferred type for Option composed with StateT monad transformer

Tags: scala, haskell, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I'm somewhat familiar with Haskell monad transformers, but new to Scalaz (version 7).  I made (what I thought was) a straightforward translation from the following Haskell code:

```hs
import Control.Monad.State

type Pass a = StateT String Maybe a

monadTest :: Pass String
monadTest = do
    s <- get
    return s
```

to this Scala code:

```scala
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object StateTest {
  type Pass[A] = StateT[Option, String, A]

  def monadTest: Pass[String] =
    for {
      s <- get[String]
    } yield s
}
```

The Haskell code compiles.  The Scala fails to compile, with the following error:

```
[error] .../StateTest.scala:9: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scalaz.IndexedStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,String,String,String]
[error]  required: StateTest.Pass[String]
[error]     (which expands to)  scalaz.IndexedStateT[Option,String,String,String]
[error]       s <- get[String]
[error]         ^
```

First, it seems scalaz implements `StateT` in terms of `IndexedStateT`.  Ok.  But, it seems that the `get[String]` monadic value is inferred to have type `StateT[Id, String, String]` instead of `StateT[Option, String, String]`.  Why?

I'm using Scala 2.10.1, scalaz 7.0.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, the call to `get[String]` is calling the `get` method of `StateFunctions`, reproduced here:

```
def get[S]: State[S, S] = init
```

Where `State[S, A]` is an alias for `StateT[Id, S, A]` which is an alias for `IndexedStateT[Id, S, S, A]`.

Because you are using `StateT`, you need to call `get` on an instance of `StateTMonadState[S, F]`, or `StateTMonadState[String, Option]` in your case. The working example is:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object StateTest {
  type Pass[A] = StateT[Option, String, A]

  val sm = StateT.stateTMonadState[String, Option]

  def monadTest: Pass[String] =
    for {
      s <- sm.get
    } yield s
}
```

The `MonadState` instance can also be resolved implicitly via `MonadState[F[_, _], S]` but it is less convenient to use due to the type lambda required. See MonadState.scala and StateT.scala for more info.